# Regex for double in Hyperledger Modeling languager

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

Is there a way to validate currency in Hyperledger, I am aware that it is possible to validate String values using regex, but I get an error when using regex for Double data type.

Here is what gives an error, it complains about the one line in the Customer defination

```
participant Customer{
 o Double balance regex=/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?/
}
```

But this works (If the data type is String instead of Double)

```
participant Customer{
 o String balance regex=/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?/
}
```

Comment: Add the error  message, and also examples of valid and invalid strings

Comment: I don't understand what you're suggesting, please kindly explain

Comment: You say `Here is what gives an error`, but we need to know what the error is. And if you want help with the regex, we need to know what you want to validate, so give examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions are only valid for Strings in Composer.

Double, Long or Integer fields may include an optional range expression, which is used to validate the contents of the field.

Comment: Could you please share any reading material with examples of how to work with ranges? Or you can give an example if you have a short one